# Issues setting up hidden service on Android

Tags: onion-services, orbot, android

I am trying to setup a hidden service on an android device but cannot seem to get it to work. I have installed Palapa server and the website is available on localhost as well as over my network (for testing) so I know the webserver is working.

I have installed Orbot and selected "Hidden Service Hosting" and set the port to the same used during the tests of the webserver on localhost above.

It generates a .onion address for me - but I cannot reach the site over TOR. I think some info is exchanged, as when I try to reach the .onion site I notice some data exchange on orbot but I receive an "Unable to Connect" error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

P.S. Worth noting I got this working on both Windows and Raspian (Rapsberry PI) so I know at least the basics... BUT could still be doing something stupid.

Comment: Same problem. Orbot shows connections going across the .onion but when I try to connect I get socks 504 error...

Comment: Activate Realy and port.I use palapa too.Write the port number 8080 on relay port.And make your phone rooted.If this things go well you can a have a .onion hostname.Use That to share your files anonymously.

Comment: what exactly do you have in your ORBot setup? have you tried "Torrc custom config" option to provide your working manual config? If you've made it work on Raspbian - it will work on Android with the same setup, it's basically a Linux-kernel-style systems, so try this!